# When exactly to use logistic instead of linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

In andrews logistic regression example of cancer, I can draw a horizontal line y=.5, (which obviously passes through y=.5 ), ten if any point is above this line y=.5 => +ve , else -ve. So then why do I need a logistic regression. Im just trying to understand the best case explanation to use logistic regression ?

[image]
As you can see in the image included , a horizontal line clearly classifies the two classes , why then go for logistic ?

Comment: Because this data is linearly separable (can be separated by a straight line) so logistic regression isn't needed. But there are non-linearly separable problems which need a curved line to separate the classes. The easiest example of a non-linearly separable problem is XOR, if you plot the true and falses in a graph for XOR you'll find you can't separate them with a single straight line but you need a curved one instead

Comment: So first we should plot our training data, check whether its linearly seperable or not then whenever the data is non-linearly seperable we should go for logistic. Is that how we should proceed.

Comment: That's a perfectly fine way of doing it for some data, although it can get harder for higher dimensioned data. But plotting things like histograms for different features etc to analyse the data before choosing a model can make things easier.

Answer (score 4):

In short, when you need [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification), i.e. to predict one of predefined (nominal) classes, use logistic regression; when you need [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), i.e. to predict quantitative value, use linear regression.

Also linear regression assumes the linear dependency between inputs (features) and outcomes, while logistic regression assumes the outcomes to be distributed as a binomial. Response of logistic regression can be interpreted as a classifier confidence.

Take a look at answers to similar questions at [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86720/log-linear-regression-vs-logistic-regression) or [differencebetween](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-linear-and-vs-logistic-regression/).

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are confusing independent (known) and dependent (what you are trying to predict) variables in your question.

> I can draw a horizontal line y=.5, (which obviously passes through
>   y=.5 ), ten if any point is above this line y=.5 => +ve , else -ve.

Your horizontal line at 0.5 presupposes that you *know* `y`. But actually this is what you are trying to *predict* based on the known `x` (tumor size in your case).

Here is the logic. Based on "train" examples where you know `y`, you are building a model `h(x)`. Then you say: if h(x)>0.5 (or other threshold), then y=1, else y=0. Now you apply your model to the "test" set, where you know *only* `x` and you *predict* `y`.

With this in mind your  question is: does `h(x)` looks like a straight line or as logistic function? You can *not* draw a y=0.5 line, because you do not know `y`.